# griffon 2.0 eclipse error

Tags: eclipse, griffon

I created a project with griffon 2.0.0.(name: sam)

I have installed the cygwin64 along the griffon guide.

$ curl -s get.gvmtool.net | bash

$ gvm install lazybones

bintrayRepositories = [
    "griffon/griffon-lazybones-templates",
    "pledbrook/lazybones-templates"
]

$ lazybones list
Available templates in griffon/griffon-lazybones-templates:

```
griffon-javafx-java
griffon-javafx-groovy
griffon-lanterna-java
griffon-lanterna-groovy
griffon-pivot-java
griffon-pivot-groovy
griffon-swing-java
griffon-swing-groovy
griffon-plugin
```

$ lazybones create griffon-javafx-groovy sam

$ griffon integrate-with --eclipse

$ griffon install-plugin

and import in eclipse[image]

How do i resolve the error line??

my version:

eclipse:Kepler

jdk:1.8.0_25

Answer (score 0):

Griffon 2.0 no longer requires the usage of the `griffon` command. You either use `gradle` or `maven` to build the project. Pick one of these tools, then install the appropriate eclipse plugin (gradle-eclipse for gradle, m2e for maven).